# What are the mistakes in these sentences? GRE AW examples

Tags: grammar, gre

I was looking at the [sample essay responses for the GRE's Analyze an Issue task](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/analytical_writing/issue/sample_responses), and the reader commentary for those, but I don't really understand the reasons the following sentences have "serious flaws":

> The future ability of growing new brain cells

I believe an alternative could be

> The future ability ***to grow*** new brain cells

but I can't spot the problem with the first one.

The other sentence is

> One aspect where the ability of humans may initially be seen as an example of deteriorating minds

What is wrong with it?

Comment: The only problem with the other sentence is that it is not a sentence. It is a fragment. Other than that, it is impeccable English. A perfectly grammatical fragment.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I don't understand either, the reader says that there are some serious flaws and quotes those two excerpts as examples. The full sentence reads "One aspect where the ability of humans may initially be seen as an example of deteriorating minds is the use of internet and cell phones."

Comment: RegDwigнt Not sure why you say that. It's got a subject and predicate including a tensed verb.

Comment: @BillJ It's a (heavy) subject. A noun phrase.

Comment: The complete sentence you quote is poorly worded, to be sure. It's unnecessarily wordy, not to mention confusing. Perhaps those two characteristics comprise the "serious flaws." Just guessing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portion you quoted is a sentence fragment, so I'll base my answer on the complete sentence cited in one of the comments: "One aspect where the ability of humans may initially be seen as an example of deteriorating minds is the use of internet and cell phones."

The sentence is horrifically awkward to say the least, not to mention that "aspect where" is suspect usage-wise since "where" is a word used to express location and many editors would consider it nonstandard in such contexts (replacing it with e.g. "in which" depending on context)

In this case, however, I think there really would be no antidote for fixing the sentence in question save a complete rewrite. One big problem is the lack of specificity; it seems unclear what the "Internet and cell phones" are being called out as. I'd perhaps suggest something along the lines of "Two technological mediums that have resulted in the deterioration of human minds are the Internet and cell phones."

Comment: I think you might be onto something with your remark about where and in which, but I'm not 100% sure. They do use the part I quoted for the question to point out the serious flaws, so the problem should be right there. However, I agree with you, the sentence is awkward.

Comment: @maltosmat -- Would that I had come up with it myself :-) Actually, that use of "where" (more typically seem in e.g. "situations where" or "instances where") is often frowned upon by editors and writers alike.

Answer (score 0):

One aspect ....with two answers?
What ability?
'may be seen' ...really? Not in this sentence that's for sure.
You have used a mixture of words in-congruent with each other that are not explained with in the sentence.
Firstly what aspect, secondly what ability. Also 'where' infers the past tense therefore 'is' is inappropriate.
I think a complete rewrite is correct. Where you can explain what the 'internet' and 'cell phone' are and possibly what ability it is, that is being deteriorated.